# 3D Touch quick actions not working when called from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I'm implementing 3D touch quick actions in my app and I have the following problem:
When the app is already running and so the quick action is initiated through perform Action For Shortcut Item, it works perfectly fine. However, when the app is killed and then launched through a quick action (so didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) it does not take me to the desired view controller, but rather to the home screen of the app.

Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //... other stuff I'm doing

        if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
        shortcutItemToProcess = shortcutItem
    }
    return true
```

NOTE: I've read previous SO answers where they said that I need to return false in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when the app was launched through a quick action, so that performAction won't get called. I need to always return true however in my didFinishLaunching method because of the other things I'm handling there. I tried however to return false just to see if that causes the problem and the app still behaved the same way.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
          shortcutItemToProcess = shortcutItem
    }
```

Here is how I present the view controller:

```
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if let shortcutItem = shortcutItemToProcess {
        if shortcutItem.type == "com.myName.MyApp.myQuickAction" {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let myViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewController") as! MyViewController

            if let navVC = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController? {
                navVC.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

So this works fine when app is already running, but it lands me on the home page of my app when the app is killed. What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution?